# How to apply WCF structure in System?

Tags: wcf, architecture, frameworks, arm

Our Company is designing new system. We want to adapt different protocols such as Tcp, Http... But the tricky side is client side. The client side is using ARM based, integrated with compact .net framework. I know it can only be compatible with WCF basicHttp type connection.

Can anyone give me some suggestion as following:

1. Should I use WCF in server? If not, I can not utilize the full benefits of WCF.
2. Is any kind of chips in ARM can support full .net framework, in which I can apply WCF client?

Thanks!

Comment: I would look at using HttpClient and use WCF to expose a REST endpoint using webHttpBinding. Then you won't have all the overhead of the soap channel stack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the system will be dealing with many client request concurrency, I think it is significantly difference in performance between http and tcp.

Comment: Yes that is true - it depends on how many clients and how large is the data you are sending.

Comment: Is there any way I can consume wcf from compact .net framework? such as latest version compact 2013? I know it is based on net framework 3.9.

Comment: Sorry I don't know compact framework at all...

Comment: @anary You should benchmark WCF first. As far as I remember, it was not designed with high concurrency in mind. It will not handle high request rate. Too heavy.

Comment: @anary Also, why don't you consider something like ZeroMQ for .NET: http://zeromq.org/bindings:clr